# $o\left(x^{1+\varepsilon}\right)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ implies $O(x)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that I have shown a function $f$ is $o\left(x^{1-\varepsilon}\right)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Can I conclude that $f$ is $O(x)$? This seems intuitively right, but I can't seem to furnish a formal proof.

EDIT: The above should read $o\left(x^{1+\varepsilon}\right)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. (Actually, I have shown $o\left(x^{\varepsilon-1}\right)$ and I want to show $O\left(x^{-1}\right)$ but I assume the exponent doesn't matter. The right sign for $\varepsilon$ clearly does!)

EDIT 2: As $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: You can conclude $f(x)=O(x)$, but this is actually weaker than what you already proved.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean as $x \to 0$?

Comment: Right you all are. Apologies, I actually meant that I had shown the function was $o(x^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and I was hoping to show $O(x)$. EDIT: As $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What @BrianMoehring said.  So far the OP did not specify $x \to 0$ or $x \to\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  As $x \to \infty$, the function $f(x) = x \log x$ is $o(x^{1+\varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ by l'Hospital's rule, but it is not $O(x)$ as $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log x = \infty$.  Similarly, $g(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$ is $o(x^{\varepsilon - 1})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but it is not $O(x^{-1})$.

Comment: Good answer.  But why not write "$x \to \infty$" in there?

Comment: @GEdgar fair enough, I've added it.